# Find and replace- from a table

Tags: replace

I am a beginner in Macro, in my office I have a work like on one workbook we have two columns one column with english words and another column with russian words this file is master. I have to find and replace this english with russian in another work book with range M51(range varies), I need the macro for this.

Answer (score 0):

for the FIND and REPLACE values entered on Sheet 1, and carries out the F&R on Sheet2.

Caveats as before

```
Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Findtext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
Replacetext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Hi rJ7, I tried your code its working, thanks, but when I change the range from A1:A1000, B1:B1000 (since i have find values from A1 to A1000 and replace values from B1 to B1000) and i need to replace in all sheets of a work book can you help me?